# Create Registrant using GoToWebinar

Tags: api

I want to create a registrant for a webinar using GoToWebinar API's. I came across the code at [gotowebinar api php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273576/gotowebinar-api-php/9499747#9499747)
I provided my username and password to get the oAuth object. This worked perfectly fine as described. 
Now I want to do something like this:
I have a Registration page. When user fills in the required details, selects the 'register to webinar' option and clicks on 'Submit', I want to enrol him for that webinar using CreateRegistrant API. The problem is, I am not able to get the oAuth object without providing username and password. Is there a way to pass this programatically and create oAuth object?

Answer (score 0):

I store my API key, UserID and password in my WebConfig then read them into a Login Object for use when I do authorization. Here's how I do it in C#:

```
public class Login
{
    public string UserId
    { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GTWUserId"]; } }

    public string Password
    { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GTWPassword"]; } }

    public string APIKey
    { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GTWAPIKey"]; } }

}

public string DoAuthorize()
{
    Login lg = new Login();
    string sError = "";

    // first we need to create the uri for the web request
    string uri = String.Format("https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&user_id={0}&password={1}&client_id={2}",
                     lg.UserId, lg.Password, lg.APIKey);
    // then the request to login is created and sent. From the response
    // we need to store at least the access token and the organizer key
    // to use for further calls

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    try
    {
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        //the following lines duplicate the response stream so we can read it for
        //deserialization and also re-read it and write it out.

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            stream.Close();

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ResponseDirectLogin));
            var deserialized = (ResponseDirectLogin)ser.ReadObject(ms);
            auth.OauthToken = deserialized.AccessToken;
            auth.OrganizerKey = deserialized.OrganizerKey;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()))
            sError = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sError = String.Concat(sError, "/n", uri);
    }
    return sError;
}

 public class Auth {
    public string OauthToken { get; set; }
    public string OrganizerKey { get; set; }
}
public static Auth auth = new Auth(); // This is actually in a BaseControlelr inherited by our MVC Home Controller.

public string DoRegister(string WebinarKey)
{

    // Here we authorize if we haven't alerady
    if (auth.OauthToken == null)
    {
        sMessage = DoAuthorize();
    }
    // first we need to create the uri for the web request
    // OrganizerKey is your authorization key for the webinar organizer
    string uri = String.Format(@"https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/{0}/webinars/{1}/registrants",
                     OrganizerKey, WebinarKey);

    //then create and serialize the registrant object


    // This is for when you have questions on your webinar, you can omit them if you don't have any
    List<questions> q = GetQuestionKeys(Key, OrganizerKey);
    List<response> responses_ = new List<response>();

    foreach (var question in q)
    {
        response res1 = new response();
        res1.questionKey = question.questionKey;
        // determine which question and set the response
        if (question.question == "question")
        {
            res1.responseText = "response";
            responses_.Add(res1);
        }
    }
    var registrant = new Registrant
    {
        firstName = FirstName,
        lastName = LastName,
        email = EmailAddress,
        responses = responses_.ToArray()
    };

    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = ser.Serialize(registrant);

    // then the request to create a registrant is created and sent
    // N.B. we need to include the access token to the headers to access
    // the user's account and data

    try {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
        client.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.citrix.g2wapi-v1.1+json");
        client.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("OAuth oauth_token={0}", OAuthToken));

        try
        {
            string resp = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", json);
            var ok = ser.Deserialize<ResponseCreateRegistrantOk>(resp);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //if there is an error, e.g. the registrant exists already
            // we need an alternative deserialization
            Stream s = new MemoryStream();

            using (Stream response = e.Response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int byteCount;
                do
                {
                    byteCount = response.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    s.Write(buffer, 0, byteCount);
                } while (byteCount > 0);
            }
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            string content = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var err = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder("Registration Error\n");

                if (content.IndexOf("int_err_code") > -1)
                {
                    var dupe = ser.Deserialize<ResponseCreateRegistrantDuplicate>(err.ReadToEnd());
                    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Error Code: {0}<br />", dupe.ErrorCode));
                    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Message: {0}<br />", dupe.Message));
                }
                else
                {
                    var dupe = ser.Deserialize<ResponseCreateRegistrantDuplicate>(err.ReadToEnd());
                    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Description: {0}<br />", dupe.Description));
                    //sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Incident: {0}<br />", dupe.Incident));
                    //sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Registrant key: {0}<br />", dupe.RegistrantKey));
                    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format("Join Url: {0}<br />", dupe.JoinUrl));
                }

                sMessage = sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.Data.Add("stringInfo", "inside"); 
        return "";
    }
    return sMessage;
}
```