# Citrix PHP cURL oAuth invalidKey

Tags: php, json, curl, citrix

I am having problems with this and I don't know if anyone can help. I am having an issue with getting an oAuth key I think for this. The error I keep getting back is inValidKey and I have researched and researched. Maybe I just don't get it, but I cannot seem to pin this one.

```
<?php

class ApiClient {

    private $oauthToken;

    public function __construct($oauthToken) {
        $this->oauthToken = $oauthToken;
    }

    public function post($url, $data) {
        $data_string = json_encode($data);   

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '10');

        $headers = array(
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token={$this->oauthToken}",
                "Content-Length: " . strlen($data_string)
            );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

        $ret = curl_exec($ch);

        return json_decode($ret);
    }

    public function get($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '10');

        $headers = array(
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token={$this->oauthToken}"
            );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

        $ret = curl_exec($ch);

        return json_decode($ret);
    }

}


class Webinar {

    private $developerKey;
    private $organizerKey;
    protected $client;
    // ##########################
    private $apps = array(
        'MMT' => array(
            'developerKey' => '#######################3',
            'oauthToken' => '',
            'organizerKey' => '')
    );

    public function __construct($app = 'MMT') {
        if(!array_key_exists($app, $this->apps)) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid argument: unknown developer key');
        }
        $this->developerKey = $this->apps[$app]['developerKey'];
        $this->organizerKey = $this->apps[$app]['organizerKey'];
        $this->client = new ApiClient($this->apps[$app]['oauthToken']);
    }


    public function getUpcoming() {
        return $this->client->get("https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/{$this->organizerKey}/upcomingWebinars");
    }

    public function getHistorical() {
        return $this->client->get("https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/{$this->organizerKey}/historicalWebinars");
    }

    public function addRegistrant($webinarKey, $email, $firstname, $lastname) {
        $url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2W/rest/organizers/{$this->organizerKey}/webinars/{$webinarKey}/registrants";
        $data = (object) array(
            'firstName' => $firstname,
            'lastName' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email
        );
        return $this->client->post($url, $data);
    }

}

//****************************************************

$api = new Webinar();
print_r($api->getUpcoming));

?>
```

Comment: have you called citrix? If it is a wrong key (like the error you got...) you can try and try and try with no avail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273576/gotowebinar-api-php

That link took care of me. :)

Comment: No I didn't call. I used the script(s) as the link above and have managed to authorize correctly.

Comment: i used this code but i code the error  {
"error":"invalid_client"
} @Andrew Allen West , help me

Comment: @max25 you're going to have to start a new topic with your question in it, then link me from here to it so I can comment. I need you to paste in the exact scripts or codes you're using.