# Automatically log in to GotoWebinar account through PHP

Tags: php, integration

I have read and applied the gotowebinar-php integratation found on this link:

[gotowebinar api php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273576/gotowebinar-api-php)

I find it extremely helpful. However, my only problem now is that I want to automatically POST my username and password from my authorize.php page, so that when it is redirected to gotowebinar, it will automatically login, then after that, it will pass my upcoming gotowebinars in Array form. It is already working, but the only problem is that I have to manually enter my username and password when it is redirected to the gotowebinar page.

Is there a way to automate this through http post? Any suggestion is well appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need:
https://developer.citrixonline.com/page/direct-login

```
      $reponse = json_decode($this->make_request("https://api.citrixonline.com/G2M/rest/meetings/".$webmeetingId."?oauth_token=".$this->access_token), true);
```

Comment: Hi visualex. I tried that but it doesn't seem to fit my code. the API already do the integration for me. And I already have a code for the retrieving of the latest webinars. I only copied the code from this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273576/gotowebinar-api-php But I don't know how to integrate that Direct Login in my existing code.

Comment: Edited. This should be it, more or less, make another method, insert this and, return the response, make_request may not be the name of your method, just check.

Comment: I tried to change the link to the one you posted, but it won't work. this is actually the link: https://developer.citrixonline.com/consent/login?client_id=NPAxGrSyaFkA6uGaj0B7tdbWAbz9l7UB&access_type=G2W&app_name=gotowebinar-integration&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.globalforcestn.com%2Fauthorize.php My problem is that it still asks me to enter my username and password. I wanted to enter my username and password as a parameter (though i tried to enter it as a query string but it didn't work). Sorry because i am really a newbie here. THanks for all your help.

Comment: Correct, that is what it will do as i see from your link, Make a new method in that class of yours, name it login_direct or whatever you want and try this code: http://pastebin.com/TcqGvSw8
 in $response you have the stuff you need.